# Performance problems using Sqlite function InitSpatialMetaData() to create a Spatialite database through Python

Tags: python, sqlite, gis, spatialite

I'm creating a dynamic database through [python](/questions/tagged/python). The code above work's fine but when I use the function **InitSpatialMetadata()** in query, the database is created very slowly. 
The file starts with 0kb and it's increases something like 2-5kb per second until it is completely create. All the process takes about 2-3 minutes to complete and the final file has 3mb.
Someone already had this problem?

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/test.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()")
```

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but per [this thread on gdal-dev](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-October/037247.html), and depending on your version of the library,

```
InitSpatialMetadata(1) // Note the parameter
```

might run much faster. It did for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's building the spatial metadata into the base and 3mb is a standard size.

To speed up the request, just use a begin/commit transaction to proceed in silently mode:

```
cursor.execute("BEGIN ;")
cursor.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()")
cursor.execute("COMMIT ;")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set some pragma to make the this procedure faster:

Before execute "SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()", execute:

"PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" and
"PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY'

Then go back to the settings:

"PRAGMA synchronous = FULL" and
"PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE'

This works with me

Answer (score 0):

I found this was no longer a problem when using pyspatialite in place of the basic sqlite3 module (on Windows at least) - https://github.com/lokkju/pyspatialite